# Why does changing my div class to a form change the functionality of my website

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a file upload for my website, and when I try to change the div with the id of "cool-border" to a form element to be able to upload the file, my code no longer works. Wen I select a file, the file name is no longer displayed in the file text span. I cut out some code for the dragging and dropping process to declutter but yeah, I'm pretty confused

sorry for the wonky scaling lol i havent made it responsive

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
}

#dropContainer {
    border-radius: 1em;
    color: #effffb;
    background-color: #6cd89d;
    
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
    max-width: 50vh;
}

#fakeButton {
    background-color: #a5a5a5;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #effffb;
}
#fakeButton:hover{
    background-color: #5c5c5c;
}


span {
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#cool-border {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #effffb 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, #effffb 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, #effffb 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, #effffb 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
    background-size: 15px 2px, 15px 2px, 2px 15px, 2px 15px;
    background-position: left top, right bottom, left bottom, right   top;
    animation: border-dance 1s infinite linear;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 1em;
}

@keyframes border-dance {
    0% {
      background-position: left top, right bottom, left bottom, right   top;
    }
    100% {
      background-position: left 15px top, right 15px bottom , left bottom 15px , right   top 15px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>File Upload</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="dropContainer">
        <div id="cool-border">
            Drag and drop a file
            <br>
            or
            <br>
            <input type="file" id="fileInput" hidden="hidden" />
            <button id="fakeButton">Select a file</button>
            <span id="fileText">No file selected</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        const dropContainer = document.getElementById("dropContainer");
        const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
        const fakeButton = document.getElementById("fakeButton");
        const fileText = document.getElementById("fileText");
        fakeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            fileInput.click();
        });
        
        function setFileName() {
            if (fileInput.value) {
                fileText.innerHTML = fileInput.value.match(/[\/\\]([\w\d\s\.\-\(\)]+)$/)[1];
            } else {
                fileText.innerHTML = "No file selected";
            }
        }

        fileInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
            setFileName();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I found a fix to the problem, but I'm still not sure as to why html behaves like this. My answer ended up just being putting a form element around just the input element, not the div content, but yea I would still love answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button needs to have the type="button" attribute like so:

```
<button type="button" id="fakeButton">Select a file</button>
```

Otherwise it acts as a submit button, which basically does a browser refresh if no action is specified.

> **type:** 
>   The default behavior of the button. 
>   Possible values are:
>   The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified for buttons associated with a form, or if the attribute is an empty or invalid value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: That makes so much sense, I totally forgot about that. Thanks.